# How to filter autocomplete datas from array with 20 thousand element?

Tags: javascript, arrays

(My code is all about HTML and Javascript) I have an array with 20 thousand elements. and I want to autocomplete a search box (with onchange event). And I'm using this code

```
if(sozler[i].startsWith(writtenText)) {
    commonWords.innerHTML += '<li>' + sozler[i] + '</li>';
}
```

but it takes so many time. is there any optimal version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend dividing them in alphabetical order as different sections like this:

```
let data={
    "a":[
            "aabc",
            "abcd",
            "accdsd",
            "apple",
            "azsdfsdf"
    ],
    "b":[
            "ba",
            "bc",
            "bddkjfn"
    ]
}
```

after that use the first letter in the search key to access one of the array from the object, where the data is split from a-z

```
let writtenText="apple"; // search key

sozler[writtenText[0]].forEach(word=>{
    if(word.startWith(writtenText))
    {
        commonWords.innerHTML += '<li>' + word + '</li>';
    }
});
```

By this method you are dividing data into 26 sections (a-z) and when you pick any array from the data the number of elements will be significantly less than original and will be faster.

In case you don't know how to convert the array to the data format I have shown use this function

```
function convertData(data)
{
    let result={};
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("").forEach(key=>{
        result[key]=[];
    });
    data.forEach(word=>{
        result[word[0]].push(word);
    });
    return result;
}
```

store the result in a json file or as you like and remember `convertData()` is meant for one time use, after executing, save the data in some form for later use.

In case you need better performance in the html rendering side, then replace

```
commonWords.innerHTML += '<li>' + word + '</li>';
```

with

```
let li=document.createElement("li");
li.innerHTML=word;
commonWords.appendChild(li);
```

the number of lines in the second one is more but it performs well when adding a huge number of nodes in html, It is well explained in this article [innerHTML vs createElement](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-innerhtml-vs-createelement) , using `innerHTML+=` will make the browser to re-render the other sibling elements , but the `appendChild()` does not.

Comment: This should reduce the execution time to great extent. I was also brainstorming on other implementation for same problem.

Comment: Practice hackerrank, codewars, leetcode etc. you will learn to optimize problems, I got this idea by combining database indexing and hashmap

Comment: there is a more complicated solution for this, using `trie data structure` (not tree it is trie), which will be accessible in linear time and might consume a little bit of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably is not only a matter of search performance but also a matter of render performance, if you happen to have a query that matches 10000 elements or so it would be quite a heavy operation for your browser to render that many results.

My suggestion is to split the elements to be rendered and lazy render the rest of them, with this approach you prevent your browser from rendering many elements at once and instead you render them on demand.

A working example would be the next:

```js
const bigData = Array.from({ length: 10000 }).map(
    (_, i) => `Element #${i + 1}`
);

const LOAD_BATCH = 40;
const SCROLL_PERCENTAGE = 0.8

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const input = document.querySelector("input");
    const resultsBox = document.querySelector('.results')

    let currentResults = []
    let currentQuery = ''
    let currentIdx = 0;

    input.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
        const query = event.target.value;
        const queryMatch = bigData.filter((data) =>
            data.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
        );
        currentQuery = query;
        currentResults = queryMatch;

        resultsBox.innerHTML = '';

        const maxIdx = Math.min(LOAD_BATCH, currentResults.length)
        currentIdx = maxIdx

        for (let i = 0; i < maxIdx; i++) {
            const li = document.createElement('li')

            li.textContent = queryMatch[i]
            li.classList.add('match')
            resultsBox.appendChild(li)
        }
    });

    resultsBox.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        if (!currentQuery) return;

        const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } = resultsBox;
        const scrollPercentage = scrollTop / (scrollHeight - clientHeight);

        if (scrollPercentage < SCROLL_PERCENTAGE) return;

        const maxIdx = Math.min(currentIdx + LOAD_BATCH, currentResults.length);

        /* Render next batch */
        for (let i = currentIdx; i < maxIdx; i++) {
            if (currentIdx >= currentResults.length) return;

            const li = document.createElement('li')

            li.textContent = currentResults[i]
            li.classList.add('match')
            resultsBox.appendChild(li)
        }

        currentIdx = maxIdx;
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

input {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.results {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.match {
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid indigo;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search something...">
        <div class="results">
        </div>
    </div>    

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I load an initial batch of elements that match the query and if the user keeps scrolling then I render the rest of the elements that still match but haven't been rendered after reaching a given scroll threshold.

You can use this Lazy rendering approach along with some optimizations in your search algorithms, usually your browser could handle a basic query in a set of 20000 simple elements, mostly the performance issues come on the render phase, but if you happen to have performance problems with the query you could go with the algorithmic approach as well.

Comment: @ Daniel Rodríguez Meza, thanks for your labor